# Zero variance but non-zero skewness

Tags: variance, density-function, skewness, moment-generating-function, cumulants

I was thinking of a hypothetical distribution where the mean(first cumulant) is non-zero, second cumulant(variance) is zero, and the third cumulant(skewness) is non-zero. The higher order cumulants are all zero. Can this distribution exist? Can the distribution have non-zero skewness if the variance is zero? If it does exist, what could be an example of it? Say we have some finite values for the first and third cumulants(thus, we can write the cumulant generating function), how can we construct the probability distribution only from the cumulant generating function? Inverse fourier transform of the moment generating function would have an exponential with a polynomial of degree three, so how would we be able to solve it in that case?

Comment: If the second cumulant is zero, then so are all the 3rd and higher cumulants. For a given mean, there is only one distribution with zero variance and it has point mass at the mean.

Comment: You cannot write arbitrary polynomials for the cumulant generating function. If you attempt to put the 2nd cumulant coef to zero and the 3rd cumulant coef nonzero, then the cgf has no inverse.

Comment: The third cumulant is the same as the third central moment, but this is not the skewness (which is the third central moment descaled, i.e. divided by the cube of the standard deviation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the variance is 0 then all the values have to be the same and there can't be any skew.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you tell me if I had chosen the mean to be zero instead of the variance, with a non-zero skewness and non-zero variance and all the higher order cumulants to be zero, would it represent a possible probability distribution?

Comment: I don't know. You can certainly have non-zero skewness with a mean of 0 but I am not sure about all the higher order cumulants, especially the odd numbered ones.

Comment: $-3,1,2$ has zero mean, non-zero variance and non-zero skewness. Many other examples.

Comment: While I can see how this logically follows from all the values being the same, I'm having trouble with the intuition. in terms of the MGF, how does the second derivative being zero force all further derivatives to be zero?